# Disappearing Appendices after running BibTeX

Tags: compiling, appendices

I am working with http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

After running BibTeX and PDFLaTeX twice my Appendices disappearing.

How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Do they reappear after another compile run? Has the appendix moved a few pages back or forth?

Comment: I run PDFLaTeX -BibTeX-PDFLaTeX PDFLaTeX  for my natbib and it disappears completely, one more time does not help too, but if for example run PDFLaTeX -BibTeX-PDFLaTeX - it is still there, but natbib is not showing citations correctly.

Comment: If I put appendices in front of references - it works.

Comment: Did you change the content of the template or does this happen from the beginning (i.e. no changes). It is possible that you generated faulty input in the database.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I would like to ask you: Do you still need help with this problem? If yes, please try to explain in more detail what the problem is, because now it quite unclear. If no, and everything is fine, please let us know so that we can mark this question as solved. Thanks.

Comment: It was working before I added last chapter. I have not changed anything in preamble or anything just added another chapter and it is working without it. But there is no mistake listed or anything.

Comment: @ranelya Well, we cannot really help you from distance with an issue like this. There is a mistake somewhere, likely in your code since Ulrike Fisher (a user here) told me she checked that the thesis class doesn't do this. You can only try to cut down various things in your document (of course in a separate copy) until you find out which factor, or a combination of factors, causes the issue.

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I found I guess what caused mistake. I had in one place citation command as \cite{author.year} instead of \citep or \citet .. fixed it and everything seems working again. Never thought that such thing can cause problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op has fixed an apparent input error and now reports that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found I guess what caused mistake. I had in one place citation command as `\cite{author.year}` instead of `\citep` or `\citet` .. fixed it and everything seems working again.